# Piwik change event action name

Tags: matomo

Is there simple way to change event action name by site id in piwik?
Or everything must be done manually in database?
Or transfer one action name to another?

There is a way to delete everything by site id

```
DELETE FROM piwik_log_visit WHERE idsite = X;
DELETE FROM piwik_log_link_visit_action WHERE idsite = X; 
DELETE FROM piwik_log_conversion WHERE idsite = X; 
DELETE FROM piwik_log_conversion_item WHERE idsite = X;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible in the latest version of Piwik. You need to do that manually when using `phpmyadmin` to connect to your database.

sorry bro

Comment: Ahh... You ruined my morning...
But thanks for answer.

Comment: I can't really accept that. Because I'm still hope, someone has an answer I need. Maybe there is a plugin for that. Or some short script in piwik.

Comment: sure but if you dont get any answer... that's part of the deal